# Удалить app id в provision portal apple?

Tags: xcode, ios, apple

Коллеги, теперь удалить app id в provision portal уже никак? Вижу только кнопку редактировать переходя по кторой можно только отредактировать название.

Comment: Нет, удалить никак нельзя! :(

Comment: с чем связано? есть какие-нибудь подробности?

Comment: Ответа на вопрос почему так, я не нашел.

Comment: я вот тоже не нашел по этому и спрашиваю. Может это свзяано с недавним взломом портала разработчиков эпла.

Comment: Возможно, возможно! Но компания вообще не должна отчитываться за подобного рода решения. Собственно это и написано в соглашении разработчика, на котором мы кликаем "Я согласен" не глядя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Удалить: нет
2. Скрыть: нет
3. Отключить: нет

Если Вы создали App ID придется жить с ним всю жизнь. App ID это герпес provisiong-портала. С апреля 2013 года Apple ввела возможность их удалять, но после атаки опять прикрыла. Видимо так нам с ним и жить

Comment: да будет хаос в provisiong-портале. спасибо!

Comment: переименвать можно

Comment: верно. Спасибо, поправил